# not found: value Login error occured

Tags: hibernate, scala

not found: value Login  error occured,Here Login is my domain

```
def findAll():List[Login]= {
  var config: AnnotationConfiguration = new AnnotationConfiguration
  /*Error:*/ config.addAnnotatedClass(Login.Class)
  var factory: SessionFactory = config.configure().buildSessionFactory()
  var session: Session = factory.getCurrentSession()
  session.beginTransaction()
  var queryString = "from LW_LOGIN"
  var queryResult: Query = session.createQuery(queryString)
  var allUsers = queryResult.list()
  return allUsers.asInstanceOf[List[Login]];  
}
```

Here Login is my domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least 2 errors in your code.

1. `Login.Class` to work in scala would mean, that you have a singleton (`object`) named `Login`, that contains another singleton `Class`, that is of type `Class[A]`. I guess what you want is `classOf[Login]`.
2. `return allUsers.asInstanceOf[List[Login]];`

First you shouldn't use `return`, because scala uses the last statement as return value and also `;` isn't necessary. Second you can't cast a `java.util.List` to a `scala.collection.List`. import `scala.collection.JavaConverters._` and use `allUsers.asScala` instead.